# Angle to side of rectangle

Tags: vectors

The title is probably misleading (if I knew what to call it I'm sure I'd have found my answer searching), so here's a graphic demonstrating what I mean.

[image: graphic]

Basically, say I have either an angle (in radians, I used degrees only for clarity) or, preferably, a normal vector $(x,y)$ "pointing" the same way ($(0.7,0.7)$ being the same as the red line at $270\deg$). How would I translate that to a point on the side of a rectangle?

In the particular case I'm working with, as seen in the graphic, I'm working with sides from -1 to 1. There's probably a word for all of this but I'm not fluent in maths lingo, so hopefully the visual explains my question well enough.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a little odd and confusing to see you've written $\;270^\circ\;$ for the angle the red line forms...with **what** ? It is customary to measure angles, both in radians and degrees, from the positive direction of the $\;x$- axis and counter clockwise to the other line, so here it should be an angle of about $\;50^\circ\;$ or so. Why then did you mark $\;270^\circ\;$ ?

Comment: Apologies, it's 315. I'm using this in an application where 0 degrees begins as marked in the graphic and goes around clockwise. It's what I'm used to since this is how it is processed in the language I'm using (I didn't feel that bit was necessary since this isn't SO).

Comment: Then perhaps you will have to "translate" some stuff being answered/commented to you as in physics/mathematics angles are *usually* measured counter clockwise (though in physics is more usual to make changes on this than in maths.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring angles of vectors "anchored" at the origin, we can see the rectangle's vertices are joined to the origin by vectors with angles

$$\begin{align*}(1,1)&\longrightarrow 45^\circ=\frac\pi4\; Rad.\\
(-1,1)&\longrightarrow 135^\circ=\frac{3\pi}4\;Rad. \\
(-1,-1)&\longrightarrow 225^\circ=\frac{5\pi}4\;Rad.\\
(1,-1)&\longrightarrow315^\circ=\frac{7\pi}4\;Rad.\end{align*}$$

Thus for instance, any vector with forming with the positive direction of the $\;x$-axis an angle $\;\theta\;,\;\;\frac\pi4 <\theta<\frac{2\pi}4\;$ will intersect the upper side of the rectange, which is on the straight horizontal line $\;y=1\;$ ,  and similarly with the other cases.

Now, how to calculate the coordinates where such a vector intersects the rectangle: take a vector, which is only a segment of a line $\;y=mx\;$ , with $\;m=\tan\theta\;$, and solve the equation

$$mx=1\iff x=\frac1m=\frac1{\tan\theta}=\cot\theta$$

and you're done since then you already have the abscissa $\;x\;$ and, of course, you know the ordinate $\;y\;$, which in the above example is $\;y=1\;$, so your point on the rectangle is $\;\left(\cot\theta\,,\,1\right)\;$

Comment: Forgive me if you answered this and it flew over my head, but basically I would end up with multiple conditions based on the angle/signs of the vector?

Comment: No if you know what the range of the angle is, @fay .

Comment: I'm sure you gave me everything I asked for, I'm just not as mathematically literate as I'd hoped. Going to accept it and mull it over until I can translate it, as you said, into my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the angle (in counter-clockwise direction) is $\alpha$, you get the following coöridates on the unit circle:
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} \cos \alpha\\ \sin\alpha\end{matrix}\right)
$$
When $-\frac 14\pi\leq \alpha\leq \frac 14 \pi$, you want the first coördinate to be $1$, so you devide both of them by $\cos\alpha$, getting
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} 1\\ \tan\alpha\end{matrix}\right)
$$
The other cases are similar.